# How to check a range for a cell value and then insert another value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and macros and want to learn it by automating parts of my "timesheet tracking" Excel.

The idea is that I always enter the new calendar week in a cell as a reminder (so this is done manually).

What the macro shall do:

1) copy the cell which sums up all my worked hours (so one specific cell). This value is in worksheet "Week Timesheet"

2) Go and take this value, look in another worksheet ("Year Overview") if this value (the calendar week number) is in a range (the range is a list of each calendar week, so 1 up to 52, it is column A) and if so paste the copied value in the column C.

Can you help me with that? Below the code I started to do.
Thanks for your help!

```
Sub
If Worksheets("Week Timesheet").Range("K6").Value = Worksheets("Year Overview").Range("A2:53").Value Then
        Worksheets("Week Timesheet").Range("I37").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Year Overview").Select
        Range("C11").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

End If    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood right. You want to copy the week value everytime in Cell("C11")? So the value gets overwritten everytime. You better want the value to be summed up, right? I made two versions, hope it helps you:

Version (1): overwrite cell ("C11")
Version (2): summ up cell ("C11")

```
Sub insertworkinghours()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 52
    If Worksheets("Week Timesheet").Range("K6").Value = Worksheets("YearOverview").Cells(1, 1 + i).Value Then

        Worksheets("Year Overview").Range("C11").Value = Worksheets("Week Timesheet").Range("I37").Value    '(Version 1)

        Worksheets("Year Overview").Range("C11").Value = Worksheets("Year Overview").Range("C11").Value + Worksheets("Week Timesheet").Range("I37").Value    '(Version 2)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: No sorry, I missed to make this point clear. It is not supposed to sum up but rather enter the value in the same row as where it found the correct calendar week (checking the cell value in worksheet "Week Timesheet" with the range of cells in worksheet "Year Overview" and only where it matches fill the corresponding cell in column C = weekly worked hours in the specific calendar week)